# Cloudflare: Suddenly getting 403 if CDN is enabled

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I put my site behind Cloudflare last week and it has been working well. But today I woke up to an error message that my site is not accessible.

I am getting generic nginx 403 page when I am trying to access my site (same as https://community.cloudflare.com/t/why-403-forbidden-all-of-a-sudden-when-i-go-to-my-site/3453), along with 'not secure' warning in Chrome address bar.

When I disable CDN as shown in the picture, the error disappears.
[image]

I am using an SSL cert issued by Letsencrypt in my server and a Full SSL in Cloudflare. I can confirm that Letsencrypt cert has not been expired.

[image]

Any ideas how to debug this issue? I am confused as to why it was working and suddenly stopped working when nothing changed.

---

**Additional information**

When I enable the CDN, I get the following error(`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`) in Chrome's security tab:

[image]
[image]

The error I get when I `curl` the https version of the site is:

```
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'my-domain.com'
```

Comment: Enable it and see what certificate issues due you see in Chrome security tab of Developer tools? And attach that screenshot

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. I have attached a screen shot of Chrome security tab, as well as the error from `curl`.

Comment: Seems like they are not serving your domain certificate instead they are showing the Cloudflare's own SSL certificate. Recheck your configs and if the issue still exists. Delete and re-upload your certs